# Storing png file as string

Tags: c#, json

I have the following content stored as the value of a json element

[image]

When I open it in text visualizer, it appears like this

[image]

What happens to everything apart from PNG?

If this is something that string cannot hold, how can I make sure it holds the entire content? The reason I ask is I am trying to deserialize this to a C# object containing a string property but apparently that is null because of this junk content.

Do I need to encode/decode, or use UTF-8, or remove some special characters or something so that I can hold entire png content in a string variable?

Comment: How did you *create* the json? i.e. what did you give to the serializer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

png is a binary (non-text) file format. To embed that inside json, you should treat the value as either a `byte[]`, or a `string` of an *encoded* form, such as base-64 or hexadecimal. `Convert.ToBase64String` will give you the base-64 from a `byte[]`, but frankly I'd just hand your JSON serializer a `byte[]` and let *it* worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store binary data in JSON, base 64 is a good way to go:

Here's a sample of getting that string:

```
public string ImageToBase64(string path)   
{  
    using(System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path))  
    {  
        using(MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())  
        {  
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);  
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();  
            return Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);   
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Note: `var imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path); return Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);` may be more direct

Answer (score 0):

Before you send the photo or a file, base64 encode them.

```
string myPhoto = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath));
```

Then to decode it

```
byte[] tempBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(PhotoString);
```